# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string but got a object

Tags: javascript, html, ios, react-native

So I keep getting a weird error when running my app. I have done some research and none of the solutions seem to be working for my situation.

First things first, here is my code that is throwing issues:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { View, Text, TextInput, ActivityIndicator } from "react-native";
import SvgUri from "react-native-svg-uri";

import tokenStore from "../../stores/token";
import authApi from "../../api/authApi";

import { toast } from "../../helpers";

import Button from "../../components/Button";
import HeaderButton from "../../components/Button";
import ScrollWrapper from "../../components/ScrollWrapper";
import Container from "../../components/Container";
import Input from "../../components/Input";
import ContentGroup from "../../components/Content/Group";
import Label from "../../components/Label";
import Logo from "../../components/Logo";

import * as apps from "../../themes/apps";

import LoginPageStyles from "./LoginPage.styles";
import catalyst_logo_white from "../../styles/images/catalyst_logo_white.svg";

type Props = {};

export default class LoginPage extends Component<Props> {
  state = { loading: false, email: "", password: "" };

  setLoading(loading: boolean) {
    this.state.loading = true;
  }

  handleSubmit = async () => {
    this.setLoading(true);

    try {
      const token = await authApi.login(this.state.email, this.state.password);
      tokenStore.set(token);
    } catch (e) {
      toast.error("Invalid email or password");
    } finally {
      this.setLoading(false);
    }
  };

  handleForgotPassword = () => {};

  render() {
    const style = LoginPageStyles.get();

    return (
      <ScrollWrapper
        contentContainerStyle={{ flexGrow: 1, justifyContent: "center" }}
      >
        <View style={style.container}>
          <View style={style.logoContainer}>
            <SvgUri width={186} height={24} source={catalyst_logo_white} />
          </View>
          <View style={style.loginContainer}>
            <Container type="bottom">
              <Label>Login</Label>
              <Input
                size="medium"
                icon="user"
                placeholder="you@domain.com"
                onChangeText={value => this.setState({ email: value })}
                value={this.state.email}
                autoCapitalize="none"
              />
            </Container>
            <Container type="bottom">
              <Label>Password</Label>
              <Input
                size="medium"
                icon="lock"
                placeholder="Your Password"
                secureTextEntry={true}
                onChangeText={value => this.setState({ password: value })}
                value={this.state.password}
                autoCapitalize="none"
              />
            </Container>
            <Container type="bottom" alignment="full">
              <Button
                size="medium"
                style={style.submitButton}
                onPress={() => this.props.onSelectApp(apps.contentFuel)}
              >
                Login
              </Button>
            </Container>
          </View>
        </View>
        <View style={style.forgotPasswordContainer}>
          <Button
            linkTo="/forgotPassword"
            type="basic"
            size="medium"
            variant="secondary"
          >
            Forgot Password
          </Button>
        </View>
      </ScrollWrapper>
    );
  }
}
```

The troublesome code is the Buttons. I don't know why it is throwing this error:

> Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string
>   (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite
>   components) but got: object.

```
import React from "react";
import { Text } from "react-native";
import { Link } from "react-router-native";
import FontAwesome, { Icons } from "react-native-fontawesome";
import AppContext from "../../../../AppContext";
import ButtonStyles from "./Button.styles";

export default class Button extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { size, type, icon, children, onPress, variant, linkTo } = this.props;

    return (
      <AppContext.Consumer>
        {app => {
          const style = ButtonStyles.get({ app, size, type, variant });

          return (
            <Link
              to={linkTo}
              onPress={onPress}
              style={[style.body, this.props.style]}
            >
              <React.Fragment>
                {icon && (
                  <FontAwesome style={style.icon}>{Icons[icon]}</FontAwesome>
                )}
                <Text style={style.text}>{children}</Text>
              </React.Fragment>
            </Link>
          );
        }}
      </AppContext.Consumer>
    );
  }
}
```

Some of the solutions I have found is adding brackets to the Button import but that did not work. I know it is the buttons causing problems because when I remove them entirely, the app runs with no issues.

Does anyone have any idea whats wrong?

Comment: What's the value of `Icons[icon]`? Maybe you should put that in a variable first and then render it. `const IconComponent = Icons[icon]; ... <IconComponent />`

Comment: That didn't change anything. Same error. Well, it looks like I am not passing an icon when I call Button, could that be the issue?

Comment: Yes, and I'm not sure it's valid to write `Icons[icon]` either. That's why I wrote "What's the value of `Icons[icon]`".

Comment: I am trying to get it to output for me to let you know what the value is.

Comment: Whats with the AppContext you are importing? Your Button Render function returns an instance of AppContext.Consumer - maybe there lies the problem.

Comment: Does it work if you remove the `<React.Fragment>`?